# Managing Web Templates using CMS such as Orchard

Tags: html, web-development, css, cms

I want to build a new web site for a construction company. And i found many online web templates that can satisfy my Interface requirements such as these web templates:-

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53844.html

http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/52288.html

But as end users (non-technical) people will be adding/editing/removing content from the web site , so i want to be managing these web templates using CMS. I have solid knowledge in asp.net mvc and razor syntax, but i did not use any CMS system before. So i need someone to help me in answering these questions:-

- Can i use one of the above web templates inside CMS such as Orchard cms. So i can manage all the web templete componets using the CMS ?
- Now inside the web template there are sections such as “About us”, ”Contact US”, etc... so how i can manage these sections using CMS?
- There is section for projects inside the web templetes. Where each project has a series of images and description. So how i can using any CMS to add new project and its related images?. Also how i can add the project to the list of available projects inside the web site?

Can anyone advice on these points?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately web development and design questions are considered off-topic for this site, and this is also a fairly broad question. Looks like you got a good answer below though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the latest version there is a feature called Layouts which is available by default and lets you drag and drop components in a custom layout. A layout is made of rows and columns, and you can map them to a custom grid framework like bootstrap.

Then, with the Layouts module you can create Blueprints which are reusable layout elements. So as layout is providing Paragraphs, Media, and other common elements to place on your layouts, you can add you dedicated ones like About Us, Address, Blue Box, or whatever component you want. You can go even further with code and define your own fields and validation for custom elements.

You can also define Master Layouts with existing content or columns so your users can customize them when creating new pages.

In the end you will have to:
- Transform your template to an Orchard theme
- Create common Master Layouts to help your customer
- Create custom elements to drag and drop on the layouts

Ultimately you create a configurable theme, and you sell the same website to other customers using multi-tenancy.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great reply. now seems it will require too  much work to get the web templete inside the Orchard. and i think certain components might no be mapped correctly. now my intention is not to sell the web site, as i am building a web site for a construction compnay , but i do  not think they are planning to shell it to anybody.. so instead of going with the Orchard approach, i can instead of that build an asp.net web application using visual studio, add the web templete theme and its scripts to the project,

Comment: then i can create my own forms to allow users to add contents, For exmaple i can create an asp.net form to edit the "About us" section, or to create a new Serivce and upload its images. in this case i will have a control over all the functionalities and at the same time i do not have to convert the layout and master pages used inside the web templete into Orchard format?? so is building the CMS-liked feature from scratch a bad approach to consider ?

Comment: Building a CMS from scratch is really a bad idea, there are so many things to take care of ... you'd better create a static site and use external widgets for dynamic parts, like comments, contact form, ...

Comment: but as i mentioned i want to use one of the templetes i mentioned in my question,, so it is not a static site .as you mentioned i have to "Transform your template to an Orchard theme" so not sure if the whole web templete can be transformed into orchard theme or there will be some limitations and not sure how i can do so ?. second question do u mean that using a CMS is essential for any web site ? i think many web sites do not use CMS but not sure how their content is being updated ??

Comment: sorry for asking too many questions. but i have a third question . now will the web templete inside the Orchide be exactly the same as the original web template. for example if i work on the following web template http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53844.html and i integrate with Orchard,, will the web template inside Orchard be exactly the same as it currently look like? or there will be some features that will not work the same?